TensorFlow PPO model not giving model output
I'm using stable_baselines3 module based on tensorflow and created a training model with custom feedback system but train ends in seconds and then when I try to use saved data I can see it doesn't trained and not giving any output

import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
import stable_baselines3 as sb3
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from indicators import add_indicators
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  

class TradingEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TradingEnv, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.current_step = 0
        self.balance = 100000
        self.initial_balance = 100000
        self.positions = []
        self.position = 0  # 0: no position, 1: long, -1: short
        self.entry_price = 0
        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0
        self.max_drawdown = 0
        self.peak = self.balance
        self.daily_returns = []
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3)
        
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(
            low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(3,), dtype=np.float32)

    def reset(self):
        self.current_step = 0
        self.balance = 100000
        self.initial_balance = 100000
        self.positions = []
        self.position = 0
        self.entry_price = 0
        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0
        self.max_drawdown = 0
        self.peak = self.balance
        self.daily_returns = []
        return self._next_observation()

    def _next_observation(self):
        obs = np.array([
            self.balance,
            self.data['close'][self.current_step],
            self.position
        ])
        return obs

    def step(self, action):
        self._take_action(action)
        self.current_step += 1
        
        if self.current_step >= len(self.data) - 1:
            done = True
        else:
            done = False
        
        reward = self._calculate_reward()
        obs = self._next_observation()
        
        return obs, reward, done, {}

    def _take_action(self, action):
        current_price = self.data['close'][self.current_step]
        
        if action == 1 and self.position == 0:
            self.position = 1
            self.entry_price = current_price
        
        elif action == 2 and self.position == 1:
            profit_loss = calculate_profit_loss(1, self.entry_price, current_price, self.balance)
            if profit_loss is not None:
                self.balance = profit_loss
                self.positions.append(profit_loss - self.balance)
                self.position = 0

                if profit_loss > self.balance:
                    self.wins += 1
                else:
                    self.losses += 1

                self.daily_returns.append((profit_loss - self.balance) / self.balance)
                self.entry_price = current_price

        elif action == 2 and self.position == -1:
            profit_loss = calculate_profit_loss(-1, self.entry_price, current_price, self.balance)
            if profit_loss is not None:
                self.balance = profit_loss
                self.positions.append(profit_loss - self.balance)
                self.position = 0

                if profit_loss > self.balance:
                    self.wins += 1
                else:
                    self.losses += 1

                self.daily_returns.append((profit_loss - self.balance) / self.balance)
                self.entry_price = current_price

        if self.balance > self.peak:
            self.peak = self.balance
        drawdown = (self.peak - self.balance) / self.peak * 100
        if drawdown > self.max_drawdown:
            self.max_drawdown = drawdown

    def _calculate_reward(self):
        roi_percent = (self.balance - self.initial_balance) / self.initial_balance * 100

        if roi_percent < 30:
            f = 11.8
        elif roi_percent < 70:
            f = 9.5
        elif roi_percent < 140:
            f = 7.6
        elif roi_percent < 250:
            f = 6.4
        elif roi_percent < 340:
            f = 5
        elif roi_percent < 600:
            f = 3.6
        elif roi_percent < 1000:
            f = 2.46
        elif roi_percent < 1600:
            f = 1.34
        else:
            f = 0.7

        if self.losses == 0:
            win_loss_ratio = self.wins
        else:
            win_loss_ratio = self.wins / self.losses

        daily_returns = np.array(self.daily_returns)
        if len(daily_returns) > 1:
            average_daily_return = np.mean(daily_returns)
            std_dev_daily_return = np.std(daily_returns)
            if std_dev_daily_return == 0:
                sharpe_ratio = 0
            else:
                sharpe_ratio = average_daily_return / std_dev_daily_return * np.sqrt(252)
        else:
            sharpe_ratio = 0

        reward = (roi_percent * f) + (win_loss_ratio * 45) - ((self.max_drawdown * 444) / (93 - self.max_drawdown)) + (sharpe_ratio * 64)
        if np.isnan(reward):
            reward = 0
        return reward


def calculate_profit_loss(position, entry_price, exit_price, balance):
    if entry_price > 0 and exit_price > 0:
        if position == 1:
            profit_loss = (balance / entry_price) * exit_price
            profit_loss -= balance
        elif position == -1:
            profit_loss = (balance / exit_price) * entry_price
            profit_loss -= balance
        else:
            profit_loss = 0
        
        return balance + profit_loss - ((balance * 7.5) / 10000)
    return None
    
def create_train_data(data):
    price = data["close"]
    Y = np.zeros(price.shape[0])
    N = 10

    for t in range(price.shape[0] - N):
        Y[t] = (price.iloc[t + N] / price.iloc[t]) - 1.0

    margin = np.amax(Y) - np.amin(Y)
    MARGIN = 0.1
    ybuy = np.mean(Y) + margin * MARGIN
    ysell = np.mean(Y) - margin * MARGIN

    for t in range(price.shape[0] - N):
        if Y[t] > ybuy:
            Y[t] = +1
        elif Y[t] < ysell:
            Y[t] = -1 
        else:
            Y[t] = 0 

    Y_df = np.array(Y)
    X = []

    for ivme in data.columns:
        if ivme != "close" and ivme != "open" and ivme != "high" and ivme != "low":
            X.append(data[ivme])

    X = np.array(X)      
    X = np.transpose(X)

    Y3col = np.zeros((Y.shape[0], 3))
    for i in range(Y.shape[0]):
        if Y[i] == 0:
            Y3col[i, 0] = 0
            Y3col[i, 1] = 1
            Y3col[i, 2] = 0
        elif Y[i] == -1:
            Y3col[i, 0] = 1
            Y3col[i, 1] = 0
            Y3col[i, 2] = 0
        elif Y[i] == 1:
            Y3col[i, 0] = 0
            Y3col[i, 1] = 0
            Y3col[i, 2] = 1
        else:
            Y3col[i, 0] = 0
            Y3col[i, 1] = 0
            Y3col[i, 2] = 0

    return X, Y3col, price
        
data = pd.read_feather("../ETH_USDT-30m.feather")
data = add_indicators(data)

def train_env(data, fn):
    X, Y3col, price = create_train_data(data)
    data['signal'] = np.argmax(Y3col, axis=1) - 1
    env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: TradingEnv(data)])
    model = sb3.PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1)
    model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)
    model.save(fn)
    
def use_and_test_env(data, fn):
    env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: TradingEnv(data)])
    model = sb3.PPO.load(fn)
    obs = env.reset()
    for _ in range(len(data)):
        action, _states = model.predict(obs)
        obs, rewards, done, info = env.step(action)
        if done:
            break

    print("Final Balance:", env.envs[0].balance)
    
use_and_test_env(data, "example_ppo.pth")    

2024-05-21 08:21:42.074240: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cv2/../../lib64:
2024-05-21 08:21:42.074267: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Final Balance: 100000

Probably I made some logic mistakes while setting up train class but I don't actually know what is the problem
Tried to change create_train_data function and didn't work (directly adding it as "signal" column too)

I don't actually know why but after a lot of edits, it still doesn't work

isn't there anyone to help?
